# Domino web server config

Tags: dmz, ibm-domino

I am configuring a Domino web server.  I have configured it as follows:

- Web server has no connection to admin server.  Connections are initiated by the Admin server.
- Admin server has a connection document, replicating core system dbs and the application.
- Connection document is also configured for mail.  The admin server is the server configured to send mail, so I want the email to be collected from the web server when this connection initiated by the admin server is made, and for the email to simply wait on the web server until this happens.
- Both servers are in the same notes named network.

I have a situation where the email is dead and is not being collected by the admin server as it cannot find a route to deliver the email.  I thought this would be covered by them being in the same notes named network, with the admin server being the only one with config to send mail.

I don't want to have a connection from my web server to the admin server (for security reasons) - can anyone recommend a suitable configuration for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail is always push, there is no possibility to "pull" mail. As long as there is no possibility for the web- server to connect to the admin- server you will not be able to route any mail.

If you really can't open port 1352 inbound, then you need to write a little agent, that "pulls" the mail from a repository database by simply copying it to its own mail.box. We use this szenario in some places since years now, and it works well:

The Web- Server has to be configured to send all mail to a "container"- database. We usually do this by removing the web- server from the domain and give it a own addressbook with two domain- documents:

First of all a "Foreign-Domain- Document".

```
Basics
Foreign Domain Name: DummyDomain

Mail Information
Gateway server name: WebServer/Domain
Gateway mail file name: mailContainer.box
```

Then a "SMTP-Domain- Document":

```
Routing
Internet Domain:    *.*
Should be routed to Domain: DummyDomain
```

If you need "internal" mails to be routed, then you need another foreign- Domain- document, that points to the same container:

```
Basics
Foreign Domain Name: YourDomain

Mail Information
Gateway server name: WebServer/Domain
Gateway mail file name: mailContainer.box
```

Of course "mailContainer.box" needs to be manually created and Admin- Server needs full access to it. But then the agent (running every 5 Minutes) just needs a few lines of code, to cut & paste the documents into the mail.box

Comment: Thank you @Torsten - I was not aware that mail is only push.  I initially created an agent as suggested, but have now changes the config so mail can be pushed.  Thanks for your detailed response.